# Change color of certain elements in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the colour of "SceneManager" and "PlayerPrefs", and objects like that, in this snippet, and I know how to change the colour of most things, but I do not know the name in VSCode for objects like these, and am wondering if anybody knows the name to include them in "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" in settings.json.
Sorry for the lack of details, but I am learning and self taught, so I do not know the technical names for things.
[image]

Comment: Use command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope`

Comment: @rioV8 What do you mean by that? Sorry.
Edit, it comes up as variables.other.object, but typing that in doesn't woprk

Comment: Done, this is the code I had to use
```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "variable.other.object",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#8bb4f7" //Colours objects in a nicer colour
            }
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this data to my settings.json

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "variable.other.object",
        "settings": { "foreground": "#8bb4f7" }
      }
    ]
  },
```